# vmplayer 16 terminates upon VM Linux installation/startup

Tags: ubuntu, vmware-player, amd-ryzen

I am trying to run Debian 10.3 (also tried with Fedora 34) from VMWare Player 6.1.1 build-17801498 on host Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS, on AMD Ryzen 9 3900X system. Running vmplayer as user (not root).

Target OS VM creation did not go OK.
Upon creation of VM, the "Easy Setup" method collected ISO path, OS type, (for Fedora "Fedora 64-bit") user password, 20GB disk space. But the actual OS setup did not take place, when I pressed Finish, the setup tried to start with a new window opened and black background, but immediately closed with all vmplayer application terminated without any errors.

The logs in ~/.vmware seem to have "usbarm" logs, and they do not show anything fatal.
Similar with vmware UI logs.

Any ideas, how to fix?
Maybe someone had a similar issue?

Comment: "I can see the VM in the list of the left list in the UI), with installation DVD pointed to iso file"   <-- Did you complete the installation?  Once installed , it no longer points to the ISO file.

Comment: Actually it did not install, sorry did not remember it completely. I'll edit the original post.

Comment: Actually it did not install,    <-- That is why the guest is not starting.   Make a new Virtual Machine and try installing again completely.

Comment: I tried, but it the installation process cannot pass the initial information collection for the newly installed OS (see the original post).

Comment: Make sure Hardware Virtualization is enabled in BIOS to allow installation of 64-bit guest machines. That is a likely cause.

Comment: Enabling HW virtualization solved it!

Comment: I posted an answer and trust you will acknowledge it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The installation did not complete.

> But the actual OS setup did not take place, when I pressed Finish, the
> setup tried to start with a new window opened and black background,
> but immediately closed with all vmplayer application terminated
> without any errors.

Make sure Hardware Virtualization is enabled in BIOS to allow installation of 64-bit guest machines. That is a likely cause in this case.